# DT Fixed Header Frozen on all Tabs of Shiny App R

Tags: r, dt

This is an issue with the package `DT` in R, for Shiny apps.

I noticed that with the option `fixedHeader = TRUE`, the frozen header will appear on all tabs of a Shiny app. Here is an example illustrating the problem. Simply go to "Tab2" and scroll down, and the header from "Tab1" should be visible (unwanted). I would like the header to only appear on "Tab1".

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data("volcano")

ui = shinyUI(navbarPage(title = 'Navbar',
  tabPanel('Table',
           fluidPage(
             fluidRow(
               column(width = 12,
                      DT::dataTableOutput('table'))
               )
           )
  ),

  tabPanel('Tab2',
           fluidPage(
             fluidRow(
               column(width = 4,
                      style = "height:1500px;background-color:#f0f0f5;border-radius:6px 0px 0px 6px;
                      box-shadow:1px 1px 8px #888888")
             )
           )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    volcano,
    extensions = c('Buttons', 'FixedHeader'),
    options = list(
      pageLength = 100,
      fixedHeader = TRUE
    )
  )
})

runApp(list(ui=ui, server=server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: I see what you're talking about, but the effect disappeared after some time.  Maybe after having the shiny app running for 5 min...Let me know if the same happens for you.

Comment: It might behave differently if you are calling the data.table command from somewhere other than the heading portion of the code. You are executing the DT code from the navbar which persists across all pages. Try creating `outputUI()` functions to display data from a side panel or main panel

Comment: Thank you for some responses. I need this to be a bug-free GUI, and unfortunately can't tell people to wait 5 minutes for it to start behaving properly. It should just work. @Phi, how would that work with `outputUI()`? I have not used that before. How does that fit into the code above? Thanks.

Comment: Three years later, still happening -- @tsouchlarakis did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: 4 years later, still happening.

Comment: Still bugged in 2023.